# inheritance and creating objects

Tags: java, object, extends

Suppose the following classes in Java :

```
TeachingAssistant extends Graduate
```

Can I make an `object` of`Graduate` and use in `TeachingAssistant`? Example

```
TeachingAssistant TA1 = new TeachingAssistant();
Graduate grad1 = new Graduate();
grad1 = TA1; //can I do this?
TA1 = grad1;// can I do this as well?
```

Also suppose 
class A extends B and implements C
can I make objects of B and C in A?

Comment: Have you tried just testing it yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
class TeachingAssistant extends Graduate{}
class Graduate{}
```

This sums up what you can/cannot do (and why)

```
TeachingAssistant t = new TeachingAssistant(); //OK
Graduate g = new Graduate(); //OK
Graduate gt = new TeachingAssistant(); //OK
TeachingAssistant tg1= new Graduate(); //Compile error: a Graduate is NOT ALWAYS a TeachingAssistant
TeachingAssistant tg2= (TeachingAssistant) new Graduate(); //Runtime error: as previous example
TeachingAssistant tg3= (TeachingAssistant)gt; //OK: gt is an object of type TeachingAssistant 
                                              //referenced by reference of type Graduate
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a few concepts here you mentioned about.

**Composition vs Inheritance**

> Also suppose class A extends B and implements C can I make objects of
>   B and C in A?

I am going to make a assumption to say that C is a interface as you mentioned about implementing it. No, it is impossible to instantiate C in A. It is possible to declare object B in A as class attribute, but the use case of this is rare and you should reconsider your design solution if you are doing it.

**Upcasting**

```
grad1 = TA1; //can I do this?
```

Yes, you can do this, but the correct syntax should be:

```
grad1 = (Graduate) TA1;
```

**Downcasting**

```
TA1 = grad1;// can I do this as well?
```

You cannot do this. This will leads to compilation error.